# Set values of class variables with current coordinates

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following AngularJS class written in TypeScript. I'm basically trying to assign the values of the current position to two class variables but I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'longitude' of undefined at
>   SearchCtrl.setLocations

Here I paste the code of the controller.

```
export class SearchCtrl implements ISearchCtrl {

    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;

    constructor(public NgMap) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setLocations);
    }

    setLocations(position): void {
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Nano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.setLocations
```

to

```
p => this.setLocations(p)
```

or to

```
this.setLocations.bind(this)
```

Comment: It seems like the two class variables are not changing and remain undefined.

Comment: It probably means that position.coords.longitude and position.coords.latitude are undefined, then. Use your debugger.

Comment: Position was disabled, indeed! Thanks!